# How can I get data from from table2 by sending corresponding ID from table1 using thymleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

getFunction() in database class:

```
public Review getReviews(Long id) {

        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = :id";
        
        namedParameters.addValue("id", id);
        
        BeanPropertyRowMapper<Review> reviewMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Review>(Review.class);

        List<Review> reviews = jdbc.query(query, namedParameters, reviewMapper);

        if (reviews.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return reviews.get(0);
        }
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/viewReview")
public String viewReviews(Model model,Long id) {
    List<Review> review = da.getReviews(id);
    model.addAttribute("reviewList", review);
    return "view-book";
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr th:each="book : ${bookList}">
    <td th:text="${book.title}"></td>
    <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
    <td> <a href="#" th:href="@{/viewReview/} + ${book.id}">View</a></td>
</tr>
```

I have two tables 'books' and 'reviews'. When I click the first book it should display the corresponding review of the book on the next page. But instead shows 404 error. Im guessing Im missing something in my database class but not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Thymeleaf, but looking at your Controller (and the error message), the problem could be with your Controller than Database class.

Your viewReviews method is mapped for /viewReview, but you are trying to navigate to /viewReview/BOOK_ID, which is why you are getting the 404 error message.

Try updating your Controller as:

```
@GetMapping("/viewReview/{id}")
public String viewReviews(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    List<Review> review = da.getReviews(id);
    model.addAttribute("reviewList", review);
    return "view-book";
}
```